# Transferring ETH to a account

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

Recently I was writing a smart contract to transfer ETH from a account to another account. My code should transfer 100000000000 gwei but while transacting metamask pop-up shows the required amount as undefined.

My solidity code is

```
function transfer(address payable _to, uint256 _val)
        public
        payable
        returns (bool)
    {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: _val}("");
        return sent;
    }
```

My web3.js code is

```
    await contract.methods.transfer("0xC12C54d5F701fa5732ACbAD0BabEc27a8D481e6f", 100000000000).send({ from: accounts[0] });
```

I am attaching my metamask pop-up
[image: Metamask popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, that isnt how you transfer ETH, ETH transfers have their own field in the transaction object (`value`).
Why are you going through a contract when you can just transfer from an address to another directly? That just effectively doubles the amount of gas needed to make a transfer.
Now, to answer, calling your contract with web3js would look something like

```
    await contract.methods.transfer("0xC12C54d5F701fa5732ACbAD0BabEc27a8D481e6f", 100000000000).send({ from: accounts[0]k, value: '100000000000'});
```

But you can just not use your contract at all and just do

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: '0xC12C54d5F701fa5732ACbAD0BabEc27a8D481e6f', value: '100000000000'})
```